# How to use two ListView side by side?

Tags: android, listview

I want to build two listview side by side the first list with channel categories and  when clicked on the categories show list channel in the second listview and when clicked on the second listview play stream on the some activity

Comment: What have u tried for it?

Comment: i dont know how to start

Comment: what i want how to show on listview  just the tilte and image of video and hide the json and stream url

Comment: Maybe you should start by reading the documentation for ListView, or looking for examples, or ... reading a book or tutorial on Android development.

Comment: "Master Detail" view. Is what you should look for. Or "Interaction between Fragments"